# Need to save data in sql database using vb8 express

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-express

I need to save data that is entered at run time. How do I do that? I tried lots of codes. I do not get any errors in my code, but the data is not present in the database when I exit and check my data table.

Here is my code:

```
Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

Try
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirector y|\ClubDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Liquor([Product ID], [Name], [Quantity], [Cost Price], [Selling Price]) VALUES('" & Product_IDTextBox.Text & "','" & NameTextBox.Text & "','" & QuantityTextBox.Text & "','" & Cost_PriceTextBox.Text & "','" & Selling_PriceTextBox.Text & "')"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("added")
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
Finally
    con.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: you query is prone of `sql injection`.

Answer (score 1):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `ClubDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ClubDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...